# jQuery tablesorter sort the same across multiple tables

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have 3 tables that are all laid out the same (theads are the same), but have different data in them.

Is there a way with tablesorter (https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/) to sort multiple tables by the same column so that when a user sorts the first table by a certain column, the other 2 tables are also sorted by that same column.

Comment: Probably. Try handling one of the [sort events](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-triggers.html), then [sort the other tables](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-trigger-sort.html)

Comment: You will find [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/2485/) on the [home wiki page](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki#sorting) that sorts and filters multiple tables at once.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured this out on my own...

If you use the following, you can get the current sortList on the table:

```
var sortList = $('#table1').data().tablesorter.sortList[0];
```

It will be something like:

```
[0, 0]
```

Then its a matter of applying that sortList to the other tables and then triggering an update:

```
$(".otherTables").data().tablesorter.sortList[0] = sortList;
$(".otherTables").trigger("update");
```

I'm not sure if this is the best answer, but it does work for me.

Comment: No need to trigger an update, use the ["sorton" method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sorton) instead.